# How to draw a border at top of the linear layout

Tags: android

I have followed the example in for the gradient dividers:
http://www.connorgarvey.com/blog/?p=34

I have tried to draw a horizontal line at the BOTTOM of my linear layout.

Here is my linear layout file:

```
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/test" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon1"
    android:layout_width="32dip"
    android:layout_height="32dip"
/>
```

And I did add

```
<View
android:background="@drawable/black_white_gradient"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_above="@id/test"
/>
```

But i don't see any line at the top of the LinearLayout. And when I go to Hierarchy View and see he View (for the hort separator), the getWidth() is 0 while getHeight() is 1.

Can you please tell me what am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the orientation might be missing in the parent linearlayout view;

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
```

Or if you use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout, you can set 's layout_alignParentBottom;

```
<View android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Answer (score 4):

With the code you posted ,its perfectly fine.But the fact that the size is `1dp` may not be showing it . increase the size or as you want only a line use this default line drawable from android

```
android:background="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright" 
// this for white background only
```

I hope this will help you get what you want

Answer (score 1):

It will not be visible if the height is 1dp. Try 2dp instead:

`<View
android:background="@drawable/black_white_gradient"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="2dp"
android:layout_above="@id/test"
/>`

Answer (score 1):

The black border is only shown if the size is at least 2dp. Try removing the border, and set the solid color to black:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#000" />
</shape>
```

Than you can use a height of 1dp again.